# Returning 2 different values using using a mock service while unit testing in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable

Summary of the issue :

**How to call multiple values using the same service inside the same test spec and check to see if it works exactly as in the component?**

I am using Angular7+.

Let there be a component ( say A ) with a service injected into it.

Suppose , there is a **getNumber** function in the same **service** with 2 parameters namely **( "Key" , "Value" )** where "Key" can only be either **num1** or **num2** and "Value" can be any **integer**.

This function returns an object in this format : **{ "Key" : num1 or num2 , "Value" : number }** and this object is stored in another object ( say **Total** ) as its elements. Example :

```
export class A implements OnInit{
 Total={"sum":["num1","num2"],"amount":0};

 constructor(private service: SomeService) {}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.loadFunc();
    }

    private loadFunc(){
        this.service.getNumber("num1",12).subscribe(res =>{
                Total[res.Key] = res.Value;
        },err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

        this.service.getNumber("num2",13).subscribe(res =>{
                Total[res.Key] = res.Value;
        },err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

        this.calculate();
    }

    private calculate(){
        //For elements in Total.sum array iterate over them and store the value in any other key say amount.
        for(const keys of Total["sum"]){
            if(Total[keys]){
                Total["amount"] += Total[keys];
            }
        }
        console.log(Total["amount"]);      // Outputs to 25
    }
}

So Total would become : 
Total = { "num1":12 , "num2":13 ,"sum":["num1","num2"],"amount":25};
```

Now in **unit testing** the component with the service, i have a mockService stub with a getNumber function and i am doing something like this :

```
mockServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getNumber']); // done before testbed.createComponent()

// Inside Test
mockServiceStub.getNumber.and.returnValue(of({"Key":"num1", "Value":12}));
fixture.ngOnInit();
console.log(component.Total.amount); // outputs 12

mockServiceStub.getNumber.and.returnValue(of({"Key":"num2", "Value":13}));
fixture.ngOnInit();
console.log(component.Total.amount); // outputs 13
expect(component.Total.sum).toEqual(25); // throws error 'Expected 13 to equal 25'
```

I actually wanted both the values to combine i.e in my test,
i first gave a return value of 12 with " num1 " as key and then 13 with " num2 " as key, and i expected the output to be 25 ( 12 + 13 ).

Comment: hmm i never see you calling calculate on your testscript. I feel like I need to see more of your test code and the actual implementation of your component. What is answer exactly? How do you inject the service as stub into the component?

Comment: I did not need to call calculate as on doing fixture.detectChanges() ngOnInit gets called and inside it calculate also. The answer should be ( according to me ) since i called first time with the value 12 and second time with the value 13, so on calling calculate the second time the sum should be 25. However it is showing 12 only.

Comment: mockServiceStub.getNumber.and.returnValues(of({"Key":"num1", "Value":12}),of({"Key":"num1", "Value":13})); try this

Comment: No man, not working.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Please check my latest edit to the question.. i tried to explain and change it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked.. returnValues with 2 different values:

```js
mockServiceStub.getNumber.and.returnValues(of({"Key":"num1", "Value":12}, {"Key":"num2", "Value":13}));
fixture.detectChanges();     
expect(component.Total.sum).toEqual(25);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```js
mockServiceStub.getNumber.and.returnValues( of ({
  "Key": "num1",
  "Value": 12
},{
  "Key": "num2",
  "Value": 13
}));
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.Total.sum).toEqual(25);

//update

async ngOnInit() {
  await this.loadFunc();
}

private async loadFunc() {
  await this.service.getNumber("num1", 12).subscribe(res => {
    Total[res.Key] = res.Value;
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  await this.service.getNumber("num2", 13).subscribe(res => {
    Total[res.Key] = res.Value;
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  this.calculate();
}
```

Comment: Sorry man, that did not work on my system. Did you try on yours?

Comment: It only takes the first value (here it is 12).. I don't know why...

Comment: I haven't tried that but seems like there is problem with ngOnInit method, as you are using asynchronous (subscriber) and then assigning in Total synchronously. I am in doubt that your code actually working.

Comment: Actual program works.. testing does not. Suppose everything was synchronous then would the testing part also work?

Comment: Also what do you suggest? Like how should I change my program?

Comment: Can you see my latest answer, and maybe help me with that.....

Comment: Use async await

Comment: I did not quite get it... can you do the needful changes? In my latest answer code/ by you own code?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Please check my latest edit to the question.. i tried to explain and change it a bit more..

Comment: I added async await. check now

Comment: Sorry man, yours is taking only the value that is 12 with key " num1 ".. Also can't it be done without adding async await? I just wanted to combine the values on mockServiceStub calls..

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?